# How to set time zones for different locations?

Tags: php, timezone

I am very much confused for setting time zones.
I am developing a forum in PHP, in that I am not sure for displaying times for replies.

Below is the condition,

One question is posted on 1 Apr 2013 10.00 am (Time zone 'Asia/Calcutta'). Someone replies it quickly on 31 Mar 2013 11.30 pm because the  time zone of replied person is 'America/Chicago' which is -10.30 hours.

My question is how to manage time zones for different locations?

In above example, What should be the time displayed to user who has posted question and get reply?

And what should be the time displayed to the user who replied for a question?

I am using time function of PHP as a string to insert time record in database.
And to display time I used

```
date("d m Y h:m a", strtotime($time));
```

Above code $time is the value comes from database.

Thanks..

Comment: use date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');

Comment: You can use one unified timezone (e.g. UTC) on your server, and use `Date.getTimezoneOffset()` on client to determine the offset of client, and output related time according to that offset.

Comment: Where do you get `$time` from? If from the user, then don't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would store dates and times into the database using `gmdate()` to make them GMT-based:

```
$d = gmdate('Y-m-d H:i:s');
// store $d into database
```

When you render the page, you take into account the user's timezone preference:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Singapore');
$ts = strtotime($date_from_db . ' GMT');
$date_on_page = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $ts);
```

Or you could let JavaScript handle the time conversion.

**Update**

You could also store UNIX timestamps in the database; Personally I like having DATETIME columns, because those are easier to decode when you're trying to debug something :)

Comment: Thanks, this is very useful. But for different user locations how can I get the timezones to set?

Comment: @Sachin You would send the time in GMT and let JavaScript handle the the timezone; if your users can set their timezone in the database you can of course handle this with PHP as well :)

Comment: Ok, but using javascript I have to store timezone in php session variable. And for big application, for many users I think it is not feasible to use sessions.

Comment: @Sachin If you're using JavaScript to process time you don't need to store time zone, because it will get formatted to the user's local time zone automatically. Btw, sessions are quite feasible, even for many users.

Comment: so, everytime on a page I want datetime then I have to call javascript function, is it right?

Comment: @Sachin Well, yeah. Like I said, you have two options basically; either let PHP write the date/time (and use the stored user's timezone preference either via database or some AJAX mechanism) or let it be handled by JavaScript itself.

Comment: I have found this to calculate local time of use. `function convertToTime(val, ele) { var tstamp = val * 1000; var t = new Date(tstamp); .... }` Will this function calculate right value in any timezone? Here val is Php time() calcualted value.

Comment: @Sachin Yes, that would do it :)

Answer (score 0):

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');
```

this function is used to use default timezone in php.

here is the link for [tutorial](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php).

And to change the timezone use:

```
$date = new DateTime('2000-01-01', new DateTimeZone('Pacific/Nauru'));
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:sP') . "\n";

$date->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('Pacific/Chatham'));
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:sP') . "\n";
```

Here is the list of [timezones](http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.asia.php).